# github actions get URL of test build

Tags: github, github-actions

I can't seem to find out how to get the URL of a test workflow anywhere in the docs.  I have a simple job which runs tests and on fail it needs to post the URL of the failed job to another web service.

I was expecting this to be in the default env vars but apparently not.

Thanks,

Comment: One person on GH forum found '[horrible workaround](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Get-Runs-Url/m-p/38518/highlight/true#M3397)' not so long ago.

Comment: @Samira that link doesn't seem to work anymore

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Here's how you construct the URL:

```
${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}
```

Comment: Too bad there is no way to directly go to logs of a given jobs. (see : https://github.community/t/get-url-to-runs-associated-to-current-job/256576)

Comment: In https://github.com/actions/github-script form: `${context.serverUrl}/${context.repo.owner}/${context.repo.repo}/actions/runs/${context.runId}`

Answer (score 4):

You can get the **GitHub Action URL** for the particular **commit** by formulating the URL like the example below for a shell script step.

```yaml
      - name: Run shell cmd
        run: echo "https://github.com/${{github.repository}}/commit/${{github.sha}}/checks/${{github.run_id}}"
```

Alternatively, GitHub action provides the `env's` as `GITHUB_REPOSITORY, GITHUB_SHA, GITHUB_RUN_ID` in each step and only need to construct the URL in the above pattern.

Comment: Additionally, if you want the checks URL for a run on a Pull Request, the sha is funny (see the doc on the github.sha property: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) so the syntax for the link to the checks on a particular commit is `${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/commit/${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}/checks/${{ github.run_id }}`

Answer (score 1):

Am convinced there is nothing about this in the docs, but I eventually found that this works:

```
https://github.com/<name>/<repo>/commit/$GITHUB_SHA/checks
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found is to just use the GitHub CLI. It's included in GitHub's Actions runners, so you just add a `run` step something like this:

```yaml
- env:
   GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
  shell: bash
  run: gh run --repo ${{ github.repository }} view ${{ github.run_id }} --json jobs --jq '.jobs[] | select(.name == "${{ github.job }}") | .url'
```

This gives me something like `https://github.com/gillegra/my-repo/actions/runs/123456789/jobs/987654321098`.

I went a step further and included a little more `jq` filtering to generate a link taking me directly to the step I'll almost always navigate to anyway:

```yaml
- env:
   GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
  shell: bash
  run: gh run --repo ${{ github.repository }} view ${{ github.run_id }} --json jobs --jq '.jobs[] | select(.name == "${{ github.job }}") | .url, (.steps[] | select(.name == "Run Cypress Tests") | "#step:\(.number):1")' | tr -d "\n"
```

This gives me something like `https://github.com/gillegra/my-repo/actions/runs/123456789/jobs/987654321012#step:9:1`.

Comment: This doesn't work for matrix and included workflows because the job name is not the same.

Comment: The question doesn't mention using matrix, but that's still a good point. Is that what's described in [this "discussion"](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/40291)?

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few discussions about the problem from different angles. There are so many ways this could be made easier from GitHub's side, but at least the job name should be consistent. So frustrating!